# Invalid product Id in InApp Purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have implemented InApp Purchase  in my App.

These are the steps i have taken

1. Created a new App Id as "QPSRWANSS5.com.cmpnyname.appname" Enabling Manage In App Purchase
2. Created Provisioning File and installed
3. In my Project Info.plist i gave Bundle Identifier like "com.cmpnyname.appname"
4. I added a binary  iTunesConnect and rejected It
5. Now added a new InApp Purchase and gave all the info needed and the InApp Purchase is in the "Waiting For Review " State now.
6. Included the storekit and added the request and response code.
7. Created a test user in my account.
8. Signed out of Apple Id in my device, Uninstalled the previous build in the device
9. Installed the new build in my device new provisioning file

Now the Output is Invalid product id: com.cmpnyname.appname.feature

Can you guys help me out where is my problem.

Another question is in my Contracts/ tax/ Banking Contracts In process / iOS Paid Applications / view bank Info there is a Information in Red

"Note: Banking update in progress, your changes should be reflected within 24 hours.
You will not be able to make any changes until your update completes processing."

But i waited for more than 48 Hours and still this doesnt go.
Does this has effect in my Invalid Product Id Output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes, more than 48h are needed..

You should take a look at this website : [InApp purchases, a full walkthrough](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/)

And always on this website : [Invalid Product Ids](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/)

Comment: Yup saw that link.. But i wanna double check with you guys.. Anyway Thanks louis...

Answer (score 2):

Yes of Course, that matter with your invalid product ID. Paid Contract should be working in order to test In-app purchase.

Answer (score 1):

I just went through all of this the last couple of days. I can verify the following

- You don't need to upload a binary to test in-app purchase.
- You don't need to use your device. You can use the simulator to test in-app purchase as long as the projects target deployment version is iOS 5.0. At least for querying the products, the simulator works fine
- In my case, the missing link was missing bank info in my itunes account

so the steps are

1. Create new app id without asterisk
2. Create new development provisioning profile and install in xcode
3. Change your app settings to use the new bundle id and provisioning profile
4. Create new app in itunes by providing stub metadata
5. Create in app purchase product and also specify a screenshot
6. From the version details page of the app, "link" the in-app product with the app

You are ready to test by using the productid of the in-app product. This worked for me without having to wait at all before running the code.

UPDATE: Actually you don't need the device for none of the steps involved in the purchase. You can complete the process by logging in with a test account IN THE SIMULATOR.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have completed all the financial requirements.

- Go to agreements,tax and banking
- Fill out all 3 columns of paid applications contract type including contact info, bank info and tax info.

Hopefully, this will resolve the issue.